# Why are successively declared pointer variables stored in memory in a decreasing order of their addresses?

Tags: c, pointers

I was running the following code and found something that I didn't understand :

```
main(){
char *s1 = "hi";
char *s2 = "Bye";
char *s3 = "Out";
printf("s %p | p %p : s %p | p %p : s %p | p %p", s1, &s1, s2, &s2, s3, &s3); 
}
```

The output to this comes out as :

```
s 0000000000409020 | p 000000000064FE58 : s 0000000000409023 | p 000000000064FE50 : s 0000000000409027 | p 000000000064FE48
```

Here we can clearly see that the strings are stored with their starting addresses in increasing order of values but the addresses of the pointer variables are in decreasing order of values - IN MEMORY.

I was just curious to know why is it so?
Shouldn't the addresses of the pointer variables be in increasing order too?

Comment: Why should it be increasing?

Comment: Stack-allocated storage often works that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numeric values of the addresses stored in `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` (that is, the addresses of the arrays of characters initialized to `"hi"`, `"Bye"`, and `"Out"`) are guaranteed not to be equal, and they are likely to be close to each other, but there is no requirement for them to be adjacent or in any particular order.  Similarly, the numeric values of the addresses `&s1`, `&s2`, and `&s3` (that is, the addresses of the local variables `s1`, `s2`, and `s3`) are guaranteed not to be equal, and are likely to be close to each other, but are not required to be adjacent or in any particular order.

`s1`, `s2`, and `s3` hold the addresses of string literals.  String literals are syntactic sugar for constant arrays with static storage duration, which means they are all allocated and initialized before your program starts running.  Since they are not the *same* array with static storage duration,<sup>1</sup> they can't have the same address, but apart from that, they could technically be anywhere in RAM.  In practice they are going to be put into a region of RAM set aside for read-only data, which means they will be near each other, but the compiler and linker lay out that region as is convenient for them and you're not supposed to rely on how they did it.

`&s1`, `&s2`, and `&s3` are the addresses of local variables.  Again, since they are not all the same variable, they can't have the same address, and again, they are likely to be close to each other because they all belong to the same function,  but again, the exact relationship of their addresses in memory is up to the compiler and you're not supposed to rely on it.  People familiar with assembly language often think that local variables would be pushed onto the hardware stack one at a time, so they should be consecutive according to the "direction in which the stack grows"<sup>2</sup>, but compiled code doesn't do it that way.  It is more convenient for a compiler to move the stack pointer *once* on entry to each function and then leave it there, creating a thing called a "stack frame".  This means the local variables effectively spring into existence all at once, and their addresses within the stack frame can be whatever is most convenient for the compiler.  (For instance, they might be sorted by size so that the smallest variables are closest to the stack pointer and can be accessed with shorter displacements.)

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a special case in the C standard which allows strings to be "deduplicated", i.e. if you write `const char *a = "foo";` at the top of one function and `const char *b = "foo";` at the top of another, the addresses stored in `a` and `b` may wind up being the same.  But your strings are not identical, so they can't be treated this way.

<sup>2</sup>Fun fact: there is no requirement for a C implementation to have a hardware stack at all, let alone one that grows in a specific direction!  It is required to support recursive function calls, but how it does that is completely unspecified.

Comment: it is the wish of the compiler designer how they want the addresses to be allocated to the variables, but isn't it the most common (and widely accepted) way to just allocate addresses in a LIFO (Stack) based order for all variables in main() and in other functions per se?

Comment: @mohitR0_0 No, as I said in my answer, they might be sorted by size, or they might be allocated in the order that they are needed after live range reduction and splitting, or ... there are probably as many different approaches to stack frame layout as there are compilers.

Answer (score 4):

The strings are stored in the `R/O - Data section` of your program.  **They can be stored in any order whatsoever that the compiler chooses**.  The local variables are stored on the stack and while those can also be stored in any order typically the stack grows down in memory while the heap grows up in memory.

Comment: The local variables do not have to be stored on the stack. All that the standard requires is that they have different addresses. Where exactly are they stored is entirely up to the implementation's discretion. They usually are indeed stored on the stack. But the compiler could reason that the addresses are never dereferenced, and give some bogus, but separate addresses instead - all while keeping the contents in registers. Or even nowhere - the string addresses could be passed as constants directly to printf, with the variables optimized out, and bogus addresses - it'd be totally OK.

Comment: Either these variables are stored on the stack, or the compiler is going to such lengths to make it look like they are, that we can't tell the difference.